# Perforce: Deleting Multiple Workspaces Through Command LIne

Tags: perforce, workspace

Is there a command line option, in Perforce, to delete multiple workspaces at once?

I have many workspaces that are not in use anymore. I would like to run a command that can delete all workspaces - where the workspace name can be an input string from a txt file. Is this possible?

Being new to P4, What I have tried (and failed) so far is:
p4 -x client -d -f c.txt
where "c.txt" is the text file that contains the list of workspaces to be deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: what error do you get from your command?

Answer (score 1):

The -x flag says to read Perforce commands from a file line by line.  In this case you're asking it to read commands from a file named "client".

I think what you really intended to do is change c.txt from a list of clients to be deleted to a bunch of lines saying:

```
client -d -f client1
client -d -f client2
...
```

That would allow you to use the command p4 -x c.txt

Comment: I'd make the lines in 'c.txt' read 'p4 client -d -f client1', 'p4 client -d -f client2', etc., and then do "sh c.txt". (Or, if you're on  Windows, make it a .bat file and run it)

Comment: I would too. I've never used p4 -x in practice, just pointing out how to fix the OP's use of p4 -x.